# OBIEE Prompt and particular SQL Result

Tags: oracle, select, prompt, case-when, obiee

reportDimMCP and reportValMCP are two different presentation variable for two prompt. i want to represent using a string the output of a select case.
i try this :

```
SELECT CASE '@{reportDimMCP}{Utilizzato}'   WHEN 'Numero' THEN  '( case '@{reportValMCP}    {NULL}' ' ||    when ||' '   Utilizzo > 0' '|| then || 'ho scelto Numero con Utilizzo > 0' ||     when ||' '  Utilizzo = 0' ' || then 'ho scelto Numero con Utilizzo = 0' || end || ')' 
FROM "Myself"
```

but doesn't work

Any idea?

Comment: Do you have any error messages with the above code?

Comment: Nothing appears. I use column prompt that is based on a fake column.
The goal is to print the formula as if it were a string result from the select case.
every time I try to use variables that kind of escape should I use to prevent it from being interpreted?

Comment: You need to provide more detail about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem that your second case is incorrectly inside quotes? i.e. should it look more like this:

```sql
case '{pvTest1}{A}' 
  when 'A' then 
    case '{pvTest2}{X}' 
       when 'X' then 'Foo' 
       else 'Bar' 
    end 
  else 'wibble' 
end
```

Comment: I know this hotel is not what I want. I expect the output from the select case recordchar is a formula that contains all the 
eg: 

select case when 'A' then 
    'Sum (case when "Misures-mymeasure (No Aggr)." "Import (No Aggr)"> 0 then 1 else 0 end'     

but all included in the string without being interpreted

Comment: Where are you putting the SELECT statement? In the column formula in an analysis criteria? Can you give an example of input values for the two PVs and what the desired string output is?